# Simultaneous 2 way exchange without trusted third party

Tags: protocol-design

**Stakeholders:**
Alice - has a message, M containing a secret, S<sub>A</sub> that Bob wants, where H(S<sub>A</sub>) is a hash which may be used by Bob to redeem some Bitcoin time-locked transaction sent previously by Alice.

Bob - has a message, M containing a secret, S<sub>B</sub> that Alice wants. Similar to Alice's situation, where H(S<sub>B</sub>) is a hash which may be used by Alice to redeem some Bitcoin time-locked transaction sent previously by Bob.

**Problem Description:**
Alice and Bob wants to exchange their messages simultaneously and both messages have a mutual dependent relationship where the invalidity of one secret should invalidate the other secret.

A ------- M<sub>A</sub> --------> B
B ------- M<sub>B</sub> --------> A

Valid(S<sub>A</sub>) i.f.f Valid(S<sub>B</sub>) when M are checked simultaneously by Alice and Bob. (i.e. if S<sub>A</sub> was found to be invalid, then S<sub>B</sub> should be invalidated and vice-versa)

I am wondering if there was a cryptographically secure protocol which enables this exchange without the need of a trusted third party acting as an escrow? If there isn't such a scheme, what other properties could be added to enable a simultaneous 2 way exchange without the need of a trusted 3rd party? (i.e. time-constraints?)

Comment: What should determine if a secret is invalid? What will the secrets be used for?

Comment: The secret when hashed by the recipient will reveal if the secret is valid.

Comment: Could your please use symbols, e.g. H() for hash etc., and a toy example to clearly show what stuffs are exactly being exchanged in the communication between Alice and Bob?

Comment: Well, they can make due with a _semi-_trutsted third party, rather than a standard trusted third party. ​ (i.e., the third party may cheat on its own but is assumed to not collude $\hspace{1.85 in}$ with either either of the main parties.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I've added more context and highlighted that the hash is mainly used as some "later" released redeem condition for some Bitcoin hash-timelocked transaction.

Comment: Is it the case that [[one of the time-locked transactions has short validity] and [the other time-locked transaction has long validity]] and both parties know which is which? ​ If yes, then the answer will depend on what "this exchange" means. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Both parties have their ow time-locked transaction that requires H(secret) from the other to redeem the output. The exchange that's going on is the secret (i.e. the input of the hash function).

Comment: What is "ow"? ​ ​

Comment: My apologies. It is meant to be "own"

Comment: I was thinking, instead of doing 1 big transaction would it be possible to break the transaction up into microtransactions (e.g. of 1 cent)? Then first make both parties do a proof of work (on a Diffie–Hellman key exchanged key) worth 1 cent and gradually do the exchange.

Comment: That would not work if the transaction was time-critical though.